Efficiency of ReRanker in RAG system for private data retrieval
I'm building a Retrieval-Augmented Generation (RAG) system to process and answer queries on private data. I understand that the ReRanker component is crucial for filtering and ordering retrieved documents by relevance. However, I have concerns about its effectiveness with domain-specific terminology in my private dataset.
In one of the DeepLearning semantic search courses, Jay Alammar from Cohere mentioned that ReRanker models are pre-trained. If that is the case, will a pre-trained ReRanker be able to accurately order the relevance of documents when it has not been trained on my specific domain data? If yes, how does it manage this? If not, what are the recommended ways to mitigate this issue and improve relevance ranking in such cases?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

One may finetune the retriever's embeddings to the specific domain data, e.g. see
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2404.14760 Section 3.2.


In a Retrieval-Augmented Generation (RAG) system, the ReRanker plays a critical role in enhancing the quality of responses by prioritizing the most relevant information from retrieved documents before they are passed to the generative model. While the addition of a ReRanker can increase the response time slightly due to the additional computation required, it significantly improves the accuracy and relevance of the answers. This trade-off is often worthwhile, as the higher-quality responses can better meet user needs, particularly in scenarios requiring precise and reliable information retrieval from private data. Thus, the overall efficiency of the RAG system is enhanced, balancing speed with the improved quality of the final output
